Really urgent help events_cpi not working as suppose?
I have a solana program that at the end of a certain TX emits an event.
On the frontend I listen to all events and proceed accordingly if I need that info.
Currently I only tested this on the devnet.
However the problem is, let's assume I am transfering tokens to a user and then after the main logic at the end of the anchor function it emits the event.
When I am confirming the tx on the frontend via phantom, if I close the tx or just reject the tx, the event still gets fired , i'm not sure why tbh, because the emiter is part of the anchor function, so if function fails, the event shall not be emmited but it is.
Raised even all commitments to 'finalized' and still got the same behaviour on solana devnet.
This is crucial for me, since Iam updating charts with the events listener, so If a user wants to f*** me up, he just initializes a tx and then cancels, the chart goes nuts.
I can add extra logic not sure how but to confirm txs before sending through the socket but doesn't seem logic to me this to happen that's why I came here.
Sample of the last part of the event on anchor.

How i am listenning on the frontend:

let me know what u guys think please
